# How to use Spring's `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to read environment variable NOT system property

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables, property-placeholder

The Spring 3.1 `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) says:

> This class is designed as a general replacement for `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in Spring 3.1 applications.

But I don't see an obvious way to replicate the functionality of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`'s *searchSystemEnvironment* property, which makes the configurer look for an *environment variable* when no system property matching the placeholder name can be found.

Note that I've seen a lot of questions on SO asking about "environment variables" and `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` but every one I've seen is *actually* asking about system properties, not environment variables.

How can I tell `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to fall back to supplying placeholder values using environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs thing to note is this snippet from the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

> Any local properties (e.g. those added via
>   `PropertiesLoaderSupport.setProperties(java.util.Properties)`,
>   `PropertiesLoaderSupport.setLocations(org.springframework.core.io.Resource...)`
>   et al.) are added as a `PropertySource`. Search precedence of local
>   properties is based on the value of the `localOverride` property, which
>   is by default false meaning that local properties are to be searched
>   last, **after all environment property sources**.

In other words, the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` has its own *local* property sources, which it searches, by default, after the property sources registered directly in the environment, ie. an instance of type [`ConfigurableEnvironment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html).

The Javadoc of `ConfigurableEnvironment`, in [`getSystemPropeties()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html#getSystemProperties--) and [`getSystemEnvironment()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html#getSystemEnvironment--), goes on to say that

> Return the value of `System.getProperties()` if allowed by the current
>   `SecurityManager`, otherwise return a map implementation that will
>   attempt to access individual keys using calls to
>   `System.getProperty(String)`.
>
> Note that most `Environment` implementations **will include this system
>   properties map as a default `PropertySource`** to be searched.
>
> [...]
>
> Return the value of `System.getenv()` if allowed by the current
>   SecurityManager, otherwise return a map implementation that will
>   attempt to access individual keys using calls to `System.getenv(String)`
>
> Note that most `Environment` implementations **will include this system
>   environment map as a default `PropertySource`** to be searched.

These *`Environment` implementations* are [`StandardEnvironment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html), which is the default Spring's `ApplicationContext` classes use.

This class Javadoc states

> In addition to the usual functions of a `ConfigurableEnvironment` such
>   as property resolution and profile-related operations, this
>   implementation configures **two default property sources**, to be searched
>   in the following order:
>
> - **system properties**
> - **system environment variables**
>
> That is, if the key `"xyz"` is present both in the JVM system properties
>   as well as in the set of environment variables for the current
>   process, the value of key `"xyz"` from system properties will return
>   from a call to `environment.getProperty("xyz")`. This ordering is chosen
>   by default because system properties are per-JVM, while environment
>   variables may be the same across many JVMs on a given system. Giving
>   system properties precedence allows for overriding of environment
>   variables on a per-JVM basis.

These property sources are mutable and re-orderable. But, to answer your question, the behavior you're requesting is already provided by default.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. And to sum it up: "It expands environment variables automagically, by default".